# Undefined symbols after adding the all_load or force_load flag in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I have an Xcode cocoa touch framework project that links to various static libraries in the "Other linker flags" option. The project can compile successfully.

However, after I add the "all_load" or "force_load" flag into the "other linker flags" field, I received numerous errors for undefined symbols for architecture arm64 or armv7.

I tried the "File" command on all the static libraries for which I'm linking against, and all of them include architectures armv7 and arm64.

I have no idea how I should go about investigating this issue...any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

[image]

Comment: Paste one sample error into your question and see if it leads anywhere.

Comment: I've added a partial screen shot. I'm not sure how much help this will be though, the errors are very specific to the symbols in the static libraries.

Comment: Are you linking your app with libstdc++ or libc++?  The missing symbols look as if they should be picked up from libc++.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried linking against both libstdc++ and libc++, neither made a difference.